# Simulate high traffic using data from log files

Tags: load-testing, stress-testing, high-load

I need to test a saas service load by sending 1000s requests/sec from multiple remote sources. The urls need to be from my access log.

Is there a service that can simulate high traffic using the data from my log files?

Comment: your going to need to write a script that parses the logs, and the use  something like wget or curl to do the http requests. You can run them in parallel with some scripting too. send the logs i may be able to do it for you.

Comment: @user37899 post that as an answer (possibly along with the script) and get yourself some free rep :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replay a log with httperf

Here are some instructions:
http://dekoder.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/replay-traffic-with-httperf/

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that currently but I want to do it from multiple sources to simulate real life better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jMeter's AccessLogSampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Apachebench ("ab") can read urls from files, but you'd have to process the access logs first.

Check out these for distributed testing:

http://grinder.sourceforge.net/

http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/

No longer developed:
http://www.slamd.com/